Bayesian updating with a heteroskedastic variance
I am trying to calculate the posterior distribution of a random variable x given the data denoted by y. Suppose y|x follows a normal distribution centered at x with a variance that is a function of x, let \sigma^2(x) denote this variance and further suppose that x follows also a normal distribution with mean \mu and variance \nu^2. Is there any technique that I could follow to compute the posterior distribution p(x|y)?
